# Error running groovy project

Tags: java, linux, windows, grails, groovy

I am trying to run a groovy project in windows `java rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt` and i got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/r
untime/BytecodeInterface8
        at rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt.<init>(Rembrandt.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstru
ctor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteN
oUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstru
ctor(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:198)
        at rembrandt.bin.Rembrandt.main(Rembrandt.groovy:383)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.Bytecod
eInterface8
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

I am using java 8. the funny thing is that i tried to run in Linux and the program worked.In Linux i am running java 7, but already tried with java 7 in windows and nothing. I am using groovy 1.7.5 and this class( BytecodeInterface8) only appear in 1.8.0 i cant understand why this run fine in Linux and not in windows. Ty for your help

Comment: I'm sure this is nothing to do with Linux or Windows but rather the issue is in your project setup or version mismatch. Check your groovy version and use the correct one which has the relevant classes

Comment: Also check your classpath

Comment: I somehow vaguely remember having this issue running groovy in Windows on certain version of 64bit JRE.

Comment: Try installing groovy  and setup your environment using  sdkman.  That will avoid clashes with groovy versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help i was having a problem with the classpath